# Regex: How to Implement Negative Lookbehind in PL/SQL

Tags: regex, plsql, negative-lookbehind

How do I match all the strings that begin with `loockup.` and end with `_id` but not prefixed by `msg`? Here below are some examples:

```
lookup.asset_id -> should match
lookup.msg_id -> shouldn't match
lookup.whateverelse_id -> should match
```

I know Oracle does not support negative lookbehind (i.e. `(?<!)`)... so I've tried to explicitly enumerate the possibilities using alternation:

```
regexp_count('i_asset := lookup.asset_id;', 'lookup\.[^\(]+([^m]|m[^s]|ms[^g])_id') <> 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('match'); -- this matches as expected
end if;

regexp_count('i_msg := lookup.msg_id;', 'lookup\.[^\(]+([^m]|m[^s]|ms[^g])_id') <> 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('match'); -- this shouldn’t match
                                   -- but it does like the previous example... why?
end if;
```

The second `regexp_count` expression should't match... but it does like the first one. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

In the real use case, I've a string that contains PL/SQL code that might contains more than one `lookup.xxx_id` instances:

```
declare
    l_source_code varchar2(2048) := '
        ...
        curry := lookup.curry_id(key_val => ''CHF'', key_type => ''asset_iso'');
        asset : = lookup.asset_id(key_val => ''UBSN''); -- this is wrong since it does
                                                        -- not specify key_type
        ...
        msg := lookup.msg_id(key_val => ''hello''); -- this is fine since msg_id does
                                                    -- not require key_type
    ';
    ...
 end;
```

I need to determine whether there is at least one wrong `lookup`, i.e. all occurrences, except `lookup.msg_id`, must also specify the `key_type` parameter.

Comment: is it a single string or a concatenation of many?  can there be many levels like 'lookup.tunnel.east.msg_id'  what about 'lookup.tunnel.east.alternative_msg_id' ?  Many ways to do this but more info is needed.

Comment: No, just one level. Is always `lookup.xyz_id(param1, param2, paramN)`.

Answer (score 1):

With `lookup\.[^\(]+([^m]|m[^s]|ms[^g])_id`, you are basically asking to check for a string

1. starting with `lookup.` denoted by `lookup\.`,
2. followed by at least one character different from `(` denoted by `[^\(]+`,
3. followed by either -- `( | | )`

   - one character different from `m` -- `[^m]`, or
   - two characters: `m` plus no `s` -- `m[^s]`, or
   - three characters: `ms` and no `g` -- `ms[^g]`, and
4. ending in `_id` denoted by `_id`.

So, for `lookup.msg_id`, the first part matches obviously, the second consumes `ms`, and leaves the `g` for the first alternative of the third.

This could be fixed by patching up the third part to be always three characters long like `lookup\.[^\(]+([^m]..|m[^s.]|ms[^g])_id`. This, however, would fail everything, where the part between `lookup.` and `_id` is not at least four characters long:

```
WITH
Input (s, r) AS (
  SELECT 'lookup.asset_id', 'should match' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'lookup.msg_id', 'shouldn''t match' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'lookup.whateverelse_id', 'should match' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'lookup.a_id', 'should match' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'lookup.ab_id', 'should match' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'lookup.abc_id', 'should match' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  r, s, INSTR(s, 'lookup.msg_id') has_msg, REGEXP_COUNT(s , 'lookup\.[^\(]+([^m]..|m[^s]|ms[^g])_id') matched FROM Input
;

|               R |                      S | HAS_MSG | MATCHED |
|-----------------|------------------------|---------|---------|
|    should match |        lookup.asset_id |       0 |       1 |
| shouldn't match |          lookup.msg_id |       1 |       0 |
|    should match | lookup.whateverelse_id |       0 |       1 |
|    should match |            lookup.a_id |       0 |       0 |
|    should match |           lookup.ab_id |       0 |       0 |
|    should match |          lookup.abc_id |       0 |       0 |
```

If you have just to make sure, there is no `msg` in the position in question, you might want to go for
`(INSTR(s, 'lookup.msg_id') = 0) AND REGEXP_COUNT(s, 'lookup\.[^\(]+_id') <> 0`

For code clarity `REGEXP_INSTR(s, 'lookup\.[^\(]+_id') > 0` might be preferable…

@j3d Just comment if further detail is required.

Comment: Thank you for your great response. What if I have more occurrences of `lookup.xxx_id` in the same string? In the real world, I need to check source code that might contain any number of matching or non-matching `lookup` instances.

Comment: @j3d Could you, please, provide more detail? In particular: Are there more 'blacklisted' tokens than just `lookup.msg_id`? What is the expected response, if a string holds both - to be matched and not to be matched tokens? What is the larger purpose of the check?

Comment: @j3d Do I get you right: (i) Originally, you wanted to single out the `msg` token in order not to apply the `keytype`check? (ii) You need to check for semantic but not for syntactic compliance - in other words: E.g., there will be no missing quotes, but the `key_type` parameter could be missing? (iii) Any other restrictions on the values to obey (case, special characters (not) allowed, etc.)?

Comment: The `key_type` parameter could be missing only when `lookup.` is followed by `msg_id`. For any other case, the `key_type` parameters must be specified (or alternatively at least two parameters must be specified).

Comment: @j3d I guess, the second blank in `asset : =` from your update is in error?

Answer (score 0):

With the requirements still being kind of vague…

1. Split the string at the semicolon.
2. Check each substring `s` to comply:

   ```
   WITH Input (s) AS (
     SELECT '   curry := lookup.curry_id(key_val => ''CHF'', key_type => ''asset_iso'');' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'curry := lookup.curry_id(key_val => ''CHF'', key_type => ''asset_iso'');' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'asset := lookup.asset_id(key_val => ''UBSN'');' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'msg := lookup.msg_id(key_val => ''hello'');' FROM DUAL
   )
   SELECT
     s
   FROM Input
   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(s, '^\s*[a-z]+\s+:=\s+lookup\.msg_id\(key_val => ''[a-zA-Z0-9]+''\);$')
    OR
    ((REGEXP_INSTR(s, '^\s*[a-z]+\s+:=\s+lookup\.msg_id') = 0)
     AND (REGEXP_INSTR(s, '[(,]\s*key_type') > 0)
     AND (REGEXP_INSTR(s,
       '^\s*[a-z]+\s+:=\s+lookup\.[a-z]+_id\(( ?key_[a-z]+ => ''[a-zA-Z_]+?'',?)+\);$') > 0)) 
   ;


   |                                                                        S |
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
   |[tab] curry := lookup.curry_id(key_val => 'CHF', key_type => 'asset_iso');|
   |      curry := lookup.curry_id(key_val => 'CHF', key_type => 'asset_iso');|
   |                                 msg := lookup.msg_id(key_val => 'hello');|
   ```

This would tolerate a superfluous comma right before the closing parenthesis. But if the input is syntactically correct, such a comma won't exist.